# Cloud9 IDE: postgres table does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm very new to cloud9 IDE, I followed [this](https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-postgresql/1573) tutorial to setup postgres. I used python pandas to load `csv` file into postgres.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
df = pd.read_csv('../few.csv')
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:passoword@localhost:5432/db')
df.to_sql("few", engine)
```

This is what I'm getting, when I try to access the `db`:

```
username=# select * from few;
ERROR:  relation "few" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from few;
```

But, table `few` exists in that `db`, because when I try to run that python script again, it shows `ValueError: Table 'few' already exists.` 
I don't know what's hapenning there. 
 
Even list commands returns no table.

```
\c db \dt
No relations found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're trying to select from a table, when you're not connected to the database yet

connect to your database first with

`\connect db` or `\c db`

running the query should work now

Comment: Still gives me the same error. Even, `\c db \dt` returns `No relations found`.

Comment: run \l to see the list of databases, so you can know the exact db you should connect to

Comment: Thanks, creating new `db`, and running everything again solved the issue.  `\c db` was useful though